# How to get rid off the stackoverflows in my quicksort implementation?

Tags: java, quicksort, stack-overflow

everybody!

I have got some stackoverflow problems with my quicksort implementation in Java with randomized pivot element for every recursive call for the quicksort as seen in the codes down below. My problem is that I have got stackoverflow at three (!) places in my codes:

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Write a description of class QuickSort1 here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class QuickSort1 implements IntSorter
{
    private int[] v;
    private Random randomGenerator;

    public QuickSort1()
    {
        randomGenerator = new Random();
    }

    public void sort(int[] v)
    {
        this.v = v;
        if(this.v.length > 0) {
            quickSort(this.v, 0, this.v.length-1);
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void quickSort(int[] v, int first, int last)
    {
        if(v.length < 2)
            return;            
        else {
            int First = first;
            int Last = last;
            int pivot = v[randomGenerator.nextInt(v.length)];

            while(First <= Last) {
                while(v[First] < pivot) {
                    First++;
                }
                while(v[Last] > pivot) {
                    Last--;
                    if(Last==0)
                        break;
                }
                if(First<=Last) {
                    int temp = v[First];
                    v[First] = v[Last];
                    v[Last] = temp;
                    First++;
                    Last--;
                }
            }

            if(first < Last)
                quickSort(v, first, Last);
            if(First < last)
                quickSort(v, First, last);
        }
    }
}
```

The error messages I get when calling sort(int[] v) is as follows:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:307)
    at QuickSort1.quickSort(QuickSort1.java:37)
    at QuickSort1.quickSort(QuickSort1.java:60)
    at QuickSort1.quickSort(QuickSort1.java:58)
```

These messages indicate stackoverflow at the lines both when the pivot element gets decided by the random generator in range between 0 (inclusive) and v.length (exclusive) and at the two recursive method calls at the end of the quickSort method.

The strange thing is that when I want to sort a few elements, then the implementation works fine. The problems with this implementation begins to come when I want to sort, for example, 1000 elements, then the StackOverflowExceptions occur and the error at line 58 and 60 gets repeated a lot of times in the terminal.

I would appreciate a lot with some help here :)

Thanks in advance!

/Confused dude

Comment: That error message you see is called a stack trace. The line at the very top is the type of error that was thrown. The rest of the lines are the method calls leading up to the error starting from top to bottom. The error occurs at `int pivot = v[randomGenerator.nextInt(v.length)];`

Comment: So you mean it is the pivot, that is decided by the random index for a vector element, that is the problem? What does it mean with the error that you described? Does the randomGenerator give some wrong inappropriate value to the pivot...?

Comment: No not exactly. Look up what a stackoverflowerror is you'll start to see why you get this error when you have to sort 1000+ elements and why you don't see this error when you have less. If Stefan Mandel's answer helped you then you should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(first < Last)
  quickSort(v, first, Last);
if(First < last)
  quickSort(v, First, last);
```

v is the complete array. It never will reach a length smaller than 2. Either partition v, or adjust the base case condition to

```
last - first < 2
```

Comment: Such as like:

if(last-first < 2)
     return;

Comment: At the vary beginning of quickSort method?

Comment: yes, first and last are the borders of the array to be sorted. If these borders are atomic (0 or 1) there is nothing to sort and you could return.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it seems work much better, I don't get any error exceptions anylonger. Thank you very much! But what do you consider about the pivot element, that is decided by a random index number? Does it look okay?

Comment: It's definitely not the problem. Stackoverflow-Exceptions come from deep recursions, and your algorithm had an infinitely deep recursion.